# C# name glitching/ghosting

Tags: c#, naming

i have picBarrier as a picturebox, for some reason, i keep getting an error about a background picturebox i deleted on something, it points it out for even when its commented out. i tried deleting-text, restarting, any suggestions?

Error   1   The name 'picBackGround' does not exist in the current contex

[image]

```
// PictureBox[] pics = {picBarrier, picEnd, picFloor;
```

Comment: Are you missing the closing `}`?

Comment: no thats a error in copying

Comment: looks like it's missing in your png as well

Comment: its commented, and it still points it out?, that is what is bothering me

Comment: did you delete it from the designer surface but not from the code behind?

Comment: Your error is about `picBackground`.. yet its highlighting `picBarrier`. Do a full Clean + Rebuild.

Comment: did you try rebuilding your project?

Comment: I deleted the background directly, i didn't do anything else, i restarted the program and it still does it, i think i will restart my computer.

Comment: That won't make a difference. Rebuild the project.

Comment: What do you mean by rebuilding? debugging?

Comment: No. Go to the Build menu in Visual Studio.. click "Clean Solution", then go back into the Build menu.. and click "Rebuild Solution". This removes all of the temp files Visual Studio uses to track stuff and re-generates them.

Comment: oh, alright i will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just gonna rep whore this one.... :>

Full Clean + Rebuild fixes this. You can tell that Visual Studio is a bit out of sync with the source because it's highlighting something completely different to what it says is the issue.

Clean + Rebuild (even though Rebuild does a Clean.. sometimes its very random in what it does.. so I always suggest a Clean + Rebuild):

[image: Clean and Rebuild]